# React-Native and Detox: cannot close location popup

Tags: ios, react-native, detox

my React-Native app is asking location permission on iOS (where I am testing), unfortunately all the tests fail because at the start the app asks location permission and with Detox I cannot target and tap on the `Allow` button in the popup.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`device.launchApp({ permissions: { location: 'inuse' } });`